# deleting cookie

Tags: servlets

how to delete cookies from client browser using a servlet??

```
      HttpSession ses=request.getSession(false);
        Cookie c[]=request.getCookies();

        for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++)  //Removing cookie, if present
        {
            if(c[i].getName().equals("UserID"))
            {
                System.out.println(c[i].getValue()+" is logging out --- Cookie Set to expire!");
                c[i].setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(c[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
```

is there any other way of deleting it????

Answer (score 1):

`setMaxAge(0)` is the only way to delete cookie. It is better to set these cookie properties while deleting :

- Path
- Domain

  ```
  Cookie c[]=request.getCookies();

  for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++)  //Removing cookie, if present
  {
      if(c[i].getName().equals("UserID"))
      {
          System.out.println(c[i].getValue()+" is logging out --- Cookie Set to expire!");
          c[i].setMaxAge(0);
          c[i].setPath(path);
          c[i].setDomain(domain);
          response.addCookie(c[i]);
          break;
      }
  }
  ```